# How do I build and install gcc5 in OS X 10.11 without Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode, gcc

Obviously installing gcc from source will require a compiler to build it; is it possible to install gcc without Xcode?

Comment: When you say Xcode without any qualifications I assume you mean the Xcode.app downloadable from the App Store weighing in at +4 GB in size.  You can simply install Xcode Command Line Tools (~200 MB) in order to compile many utilities from source code, which is my preference over downloading precompiled binaries from some sources.  See [How to Install Command Line Tools in OS X Mavericks & Yosemite (Without Xcode)](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/) which should work in later versions of OS X as well. In a Terminal run: `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find several versions of gcc for different OS X flavors here: [HPC Mac OS X](http://hpc.sourceforge.net/).

> Download my binaries, and `cd` to the download folder. Then `gunzip gcc-5.3-bin.tar.gz` (if your browser didn't do so already) and then `sudo tar -xvf gcc-5.3-bin.tar -C /`. It installs everything in /usr/local. You can invoke the Fortran 95 compiler by simply typing gfortran.
>
> [To compile other sources...] you will also need to have Apple's XCode Tools installed from the Mac App Store. With XCode 4 or better you will need to download the command-line tools as an additional step. You will find the option to download the command-line tools in XCode's Preferences. On 10.9 Mavericks or higher, you can get the command-line tools by simply typing xcode-select --install.

*Addition in square brackets by me...*

---

Please also visit [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and search for questions about the security risks associated with precompiled compilers from "unknown" sources.